# NAS attached with fstab

Tags: fstab, cifs, nas

I have successfully mounted my NAS automatically at boot using fstab, however I am noticing that if I modify the files on the NAS from another machine(windows), the linux machine network mounts do not update.  Is there a way to force the mount to update or check for differences in a time period or is this a limitation of using mounts.

If this is not possible can you recommend a different method, this is used as plex media server with all of media stored on NAS.

Thanks in advance for time and assistance.

Comment: Have you tried `cron`?

Comment: What kind of filesystem are you mounting?

Answer (score 1):

After some research I came to know its not NAT issue. It's with Plex media server.

Access Plex media server Web interface and see at advanced settings. You will have option to set media share refresh interval.

It won't happen instantly but it will happen as per interval you have mentioned.